# Area of the figure within the circle and outside a polygon

Tags: geometry, inequality, optimization, area

For which values of the parameter $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the area $S$ of the figure $F$, consisting of the points $(x,y)$ such that $$\begin{gathered}
  \max \{ \left| x \right|,y\}  \geqslant 2c \hfill \\
  {x^2} + {y^2} \leqslant 8{c^2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$ satisfies the inequality $2\pi  \leqslant S(F) \leqslant 8\pi $?

Well, now i know that for $c  \geq  0$ the are area is [image] $$S(F) = 3 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 8{c^2}\left( {\frac{\pi }{2} - \sin \frac{\pi }{2}} \right) = 6{c^2}(\pi  - 2)$$ To satisfy the inequality we must solve $$2\pi  \leqslant 6{c^2}(\pi  - 2) \leqslant 8\pi  \Leftrightarrow c \in \left[ {\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{3(\pi  - 2)}}} ,\sqrt {\frac{{4\pi }}{{3(\pi  - 2)}}} } \right]$$

For $c < 0$ the area is the whole circle

[image]

So, we have $$S(F) = 8\pi {c^2} \Rightarrow c \in \left[ { - 1, - \frac{1}{2}} \right]$$

And the final answer is $$c \in \left[ { - 1, - \frac{1}{2}} \right] \cup \left[ {\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{3(\pi  - 2)}}} ,\sqrt {\frac{{4\pi }}{{3(\pi  - 2)}}} } \right]$$

Comment: Have you at least tried to sketch the figure?

Comment: As mentioned above, sketching the figure is all that you probably need to get an expression for the area and solve this.

Comment: If you are confused on how to sketch, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RegionPlot%5B%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%3C%3D+8%29%26%26%28Max%5BAbs%5Bx%5D%2C+y%5D%3E%3D+2%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+-3%2C+3%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-3%2C+3%7D%5D

Comment: Why my question is still on hold and minused?

Answer (score 1):

First, draw the figure (see Macavity's comment for a diagram). We want to calculate the area of one of the pieces, then we can multiply by 3. Note that each piece is formed by a quarter of a circle with radius $2\sqrt2c$, and removing an isosceles right triangle from it, with leg length also $2\sqrt2c$. The area of the quarter circle is $2\pi c^2$ and the area of the isosceles right triangle is $4c^2$. So the total area of $F$ is $S=3(2\pi c^2 - 4c^2) = 6(\pi-2)c^2$. So you solve $2\pi \le 6(\pi-2)c^2 \le 8\pi$ to get that $\sqrt{\frac{1}{3(\pi-2)}} \le c \le 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{3(\pi-2)}}$

Comment: How about the case $$c < 0 \Rightarrow S(F) = 8\pi {c^2} \Rightarrow c \in \left[ { - 1, - \frac{1}{2}} \right]$$